# Problem with PageRequestManagerParserErrorException with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

I spent few hours today to try figure out the following error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

And note, I think my error is different the one below, so please don't confused with the error I am getting as this one:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
```

I had tried different solution such as disable EventValidation, RoleManager cookie etc.
PartialRender=false on script maanger it gave me another error...
XhtmlConformation type="Tranitional" doesn't work... Context.ClearError() in Application Eror doesn't help...
And I got none of the Response.Write statement in my page, or things that describe in this page:
[http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspxz)

This error is happen when I postback the page and shown as a java script error in my IE.

During the postback, what my page does it only add/remove some controls that insides the AjaxPanel.

Every Ajax page is working fine on my development machine and few other web servers I had setup.
But today when I remote login to install my app for an office, the above error was occcured.

I tried to remove the code that does dynamically add/remove control during postback and it work fines.
But that part of coded is needed.
And is strange that working on every server but just not that one.

I wonder what can I do to do further debug?  Since the error it only occurs in our customer's server(they need their server to work) it very hard for me to debug, all I can do now is just change some code that I think might solve it and upload to their server to test it.

Or what's the possible solution?

Comment: King, were you able to solve the issue? I am having the same problem, just for one of the users.
David

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981198/safari-and-asp-net-ajax-pagerequestmanager-add-endrequest-function-not-always-fi

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this error few months ago when I migrate from IE 9 to IE 10.

It seems there is(are) an(some) incompatibility issue(s) between ASP.NET AJAX Client Library 4.x and IE 10.

I found changing compatibility settings of IE, would resolve my problem.
I added following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

at top of my page as first line of html head section, before every other tags (as follow),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    ...
```

PageRequestManagerParserErrorException never occurred again, but some IE10 specific CSS3 rules did not affect because of changed compatibility setting.

I recently wrote this situation to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805516) and they told they are investigating.