# Postback not firing with Safari 5.1.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari

I am currently developing a web application in ASP.NET Framework 4 and I am experiencing problems with Safari 5.1.5. My web app is running fine with Internet Explorer 9, Firefox 11 and Chrome 18.

When I click a button with a server event (PostBack), it doesn't fire. None of them, so impossible to use the web app at all.

Is there someone who experienced that issue?

*EDIT*

For example, for a button that does a PostBack, the browser gets this code:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$cmdClose" value="Fermer" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$cmdClose&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Fields&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_MainContent_cmdClose" style="height:30px;width:150px;height: 30px" />
```

*Second EDIT*

In the JavaScript console, I get the exception PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

*Third EDIT*

The ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdClose" runat="server" Text="Fermer" Width="150px" OnClick="cmdClose_Click" ValidationGroup="Fields" Height="30px" />
```

The C#

```
protected void cmdClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ /*Some Code*/}
```

Comment: If you could provide some of your code, specifically in regards to the event binding and event handling. And, did you try to check the console for errors? Also, do you have breakpoints set on the event handlers of these buttons?

Comment: safari throw errors on javascript in some cases that other browsers not. Can you show us the page you have this issue ?

Comment: I can't provide you the page, it is a web app in local only

Comment: then check for javascript errors.

Comment: Try replacing it with `runat server`

Comment: @PankajGarg It is already runat="server". The code above is what the browser gets when the page is processed

Comment: Please post the relevant ASPX markup.

Comment: Is your viewstate very large? Safari is known to truncate large form field values - which is a problem for pages with large viewstate.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981198/safari-and-asp-net-ajax-pagerequestmanager-add-endrequest-function-not-always-fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem with [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx) site.

> Add a PostBackTrigger to your UpdatePanel that points at the button.
>   This works great if the button is declared statically through markup
>   on the page.