# In my ASP.NET app, registering a script from code-behind before a page has loaded throws an "operation aborted" error in IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-7

I understand that in IE 5.5, 6, and 7, when you modify a DOM element before it is 'closed', it throws an "operation aborted" error (this article has more information: http://www.clientcide.com/code-snippets/manipulating-the-dom/ie-and-operation-aborted/)

In my ASP.Net application, I am registering a client script block on the page during the page_load event. (I tried moving this code to the page_loadcomplete event or page_prerender event with no luck).

Here is my code (pretty basic):

```
// Checks if the handler is a Page and that the script isn't already on the Page
if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("blockUIAlert"))
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, typeof(ScriptUtilities),
        "blockUIAlert", script, true);
}
```

I'm using this same code from other AJAX postbacks in my page without a problem. This error only occurs if this code is called when the page is being loaded.

What can I do to have this code be called after the DOM elements are closed? I don't want the user to have to initiate this action manually -- I want this code to be executed as soon as the page is loaded, provided certain server-side conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using YUI, or jQuery they have js event listening functions that will run code when the DOM is done loading. I am betting that MS Ajax library has a similar function.

[jQuery Examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Events)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the answer you're looking for.

I was having the operation aborted error and like you I also knew why it happens, but I was 100% certain that I was not modifying a DOM element before it was 'closed'. Turns out the bug was in the ASP.NET AJAX client-side framework. I had to modify the client-side framework. Please see the question I posted, [Internet Explorer's Operation Aborted and Latency Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757758/internet-explorers-operation-aborted-and-latency-issue)

I also just noticed that your are using RegisterClientScriptBlock. Try ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...).

Answer (score 0):

I use the page_load event for this same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What event you attach the script on the server-side does not matter. Your problem is purely client-side and you did not provide any script. However I guess calling the function on the onload event might work. For example `<body onload='yourFunction()'>`

Comment: Well, this same script works when I call it in other parts of my code-behind (i.e. from form postbacks), so I assumed it was a problem of _when_ I was calling it.
I could call the script from clientside, but I'd like to call it based on certain server-side criteria.