# Ajax DDL not populating every time - VS2008, C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code to populate my DDL. When user gets to my page, the DDl are sometimes not populated. This only happens in production and not on dev or test. Anyone have any ideas on why this would happen?

```
   <td style="width: 100%">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="GridUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SubCategory" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="SubCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SubCategoryObjectDataSource"
                AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SubCategory_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="- None -" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Category Type" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="- None -" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SubCategoryObjectDataSource" runat="server" OnSelecting="SubCategoryObjectDataSource_Selecting"
        SelectMethod="GetSubCategories" TypeName="Util.DDLHelper">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</td>
```

Comment: You sure it is not a DB problem? For instance, does the DB in production have same values as dev and test where your retrieve the information to populate the DDl?

Comment: @ltech, you might want to look at this post I made. I believe you're having the same problem as I did. In IE, do you get operation aborted ever? In FireFox does it just not load? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757758/internet-explorers-operation-aborted-and-latency-issue and look at my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say that if it's only happening on production, then it probably has more to do with the client side code that is getting generated and run, then it has to do with the ASP code that you posted.  You might want to try and figure out of it only fails in certain browsers, all browsers,  or only (seemingly) randomly.  I can't tell from the code posted exactly when the DDL is supposed to get filled.  However, often when things fail on production, and not in development, and it's Javascript, it's because you're trying to run something before the page is fully loaded.  Perhaps the code to fill the DDL is trying to run before the page has been fully loaded.